# Is it possible to transform log entries with Grafana Loki/Promtail

Tags: logging, grafana, monitoring, grafana-loki, promtail

My setup currently uses Promtail and Grafana Loki to parse logs files. I visualize them with Grafana and want to group my log-entries into only three different log levels:

- Info
- Warning
- Error

The problem is, that the log gathered by Promtail has way more log levels (TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, WARNING, ERROR, SEVERE). Is there any way to replace the log level in Grafana Loki or Promtail? I want to transform every log entry with log level SERVERE to be transformed to log level ERROR. Every WARN should be replaced with WARNING and so on.

Is there a possible way to achieve this? I tried researching the documentation, but did not find any way to achieve this.

I'm a complete beginner with Grafana and Loki, so please be patient :)